# Nocedal & Wright — singular values bounded away from zero

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, jacobian, singular-values

On pages 255-256 of Nocedal & Wright's [Numerical Optimization](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-40065-5) (2nd edition), the authors state that the Jacobians

> $J(x)$ have their singular values uniformly bounded away from zero in the region of interest; that is, there is a constantγ $\gamma> 0$ such that $\|J(x)z\| \geq \gamma\|z\|$.

Does anyone happen to know how they have gotten to the expression $\|J(x)z\| \geq \gamma\|z\|$?

Comment: Suppose the singular value decomposition of $J=U\Sigma V^T$ where $\Sigma$ has diagonal entries $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n$. What you need to show is that $\|Jz\|\ge\gamma\|z\|$ for all $z$ if and only if all $\sigma_i\ge\gamma$. Hint: $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal, so $\|U\Sigma V^Tz\|=\|\Sigma V^Tz\|$ and $\|z\|=\|V^Tz\|$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would I be right with starting with $\|Jz\| = \|U \Sigma V^Tz\|$? Sorry, I'm new to SVD!

Comment: Yes, that's the way to start.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have it now. If we first let $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then we get $\|\mathbf{J}\mathbf{z}\| \geq \gamma \| \mathbf{x} \|$. We now use that $\mathbf{V}$ is orthogonal. Then, $\|\mathbf{x}\| = \|\mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{z} \| = \|\mathbf{z}\|$ giving us $\| \mathbf{J} \mathbf{z} \| \geq \gamma \| \mathbf{z} \|$, as required.